# Dynamically set value of "confirm password" to equal the first password field

Tags: jquery, input, passwords

I want to run a test by getting rid of the "password confirmation" field on a sign up form and see if it performs better without.

In my A/B testing solution, I set the second password input display property value to none and via jquery:

```
$('#password').keypress(function() {
    $('#password2').val($(this).val());
});
```

I tested live but it says that passwords don't match. I do see #password2 being filed with information as I type (when setting display back to block) but it seems that it would enter wrong text in #password2.

So how to repeat password correctly?

Comment: I would get rid of #password2 and implement the new signup form if it performs better without... but I'm working within an A/B testing solution and validation is made server side, so I can't just remove it.

Comment: what kind of performance boost you are expecting anyway??

Comment: If I knew, I would already have it implemented... it's part of a bigger MVT test with many variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `change` event of jquery.

```
$('#password').change(function() {
    $('#password2').val($(this).val());
});
```

I have tested in my local and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.on` jQuery method.

```
$('#password').on('change',(function()
{
    $('#password2').val($(this).val());
});
```

The `.on`(... is very new (jQuery 1.7) and it can cover the live scenario using delegated events which is a faster way to attach behavior anyway.

Official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

The `on()` event handler is designed to replace both the `.bind()` and `.delegate()` event handlers.

You can also use an eventsMap to specify multiple events attached to one element.

```
$('#password').on({
  change: function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#password2').val($(this).val());
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
  }
});
```